# How to adjust brightness and contrast on background images?

Tags: interface

Is there a way to adjust the brightness and contrast on background images?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this from inside blender, you'll have to edit the image externally :/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible at the moment, you'll have to edit the images separately before loading them in.

---

You could use textured planes instead of background images, and edit the texture in a material, however this has the disadvantage of only working in material view.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be possible using compositing. Here I attach compositing node tree with *BrightContrast* node responsible for brightness on background image (done in Blender Octane version)

[image]

I followed this [tutorial](https://henryegloff.com/how-to-render-a-background-image-in-blender-2-8/) before to make basic node tree: